# Regarding gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview in which when I click edit, update, and cancel button comes. I have a variable named status. If status=false then update should change to insert and if status=true then update should be update itself. What code do I have to write in rowcammand for this?

```
<asp:TemplateField >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit">                      
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update">                      
        </asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel">                      
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView is not designed for insert operations. You should use FormView or DetailView for the insert purpose.

Thought you can check if the record exists in **GridView_RowCommand** event, you need to filter the command of your interest using condiotnal match and write the code there.

for doing inserts with GridView this might help.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026072202/http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/articles/51360.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the id in the RowUpdating event and take it from there.  You can also offload the decision to a stored proc in the database.